# Add exclusion to github issue search

Tags: github

How can we exclude a specific label on the GitHub issue searches on the site?

ex. show only issues that has a label of "for next build" but exclude those that have a label of "fixed - ready for build"

see image below ( i want to exclude the issues highlighted in green)

[image]

Currently I use this query :

> is:issue is:open  label:"for next build"

Im not sure if it is supported or im not reading enough. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just prepend it with a `-`

```
is:issue is:open label:"for next build" -label:"fixed - ready for build"
```